# Select nodes to execute Nextflow workflow with Kubernete

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, nextflow

I have access to a cluster with a lot of nodes. I am running my Nextflow workflow using this command:

```
./nextflow kuberun user/repo -c nextflow.config -profile kubernetes -v my_pvc:/mounted_path -with-report _report.html -with-trace _trace
```

I would like to run my nextflow workflow on a specific set of nodes. I have have already labeled my nodes of interest:

```
kubectl label nodes node1 disktype=my_experiment
kubectl label nodes node2 disktype=my_experiment
kubectl label nodes node3 disktype=my_experiment
```

I am not understanding from Nextflow and Kubernete documentation how to is it possible to schedule my workflow, with the processes splitted between my nodes of interest.

I understand how to do with kubernete only: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/

But not how to the `nextflow kuberun` command.

Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one or more [process selectors](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#process-selectors) and the [pod directive](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#pod) to select the nodes using a pod label. For example, the following could be added to your 'kubernetes' profile:

```
process {

    withName: my_process {
        pod {
            nodeSelector = 'disktype=my_experiment'
         }
     }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It has helped me a lot! 
The exact syntax that worked for me was from here: https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/955


withName:FASTP {
      pod {
         nodeSelector = 'disktype=my_experiment'
      }
   }


Maybe you can edit your answer with it?

Comment: @Nine perfect, glad it helped!